# Game feeds not posting to Facebook timeline or news feed

Tags: facebook, feeds, facebook-timeline

Two weeks ago all game updates stopped showing on my Facebook news feed (home screen). I saw them sporadically on my timeline. Last week nothing was showing up. I contacted the game for support and followed all instructions to empty cache, delete cookies, check my settings for feeds to post and finally deleting one of the games and reinstalling it. Nothing worked.

These are Zynga games and I play 3 of them - none will post either to my timeline or news feed. I also went and played a game I haven't in a long time that is by a different company, Playdom, to see if the problem may be with Zynga. The game updates only posted to my timeline but not to my news feed, so I suspect possibly I inadvertently did something or there is a technical problem- not sure.

Does Facebook have the ability to prevent customers' feeds from posting and if is this what happened?

Comment: you cannot see your own posts in the your news feed.

Comment: @user221287 That's not true, and I don't think it ever was.